# How can I set this up properly, so I won't perform a state update on an unmounted component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, formik

I'm building a React app with NextJS.

1. I built a custom `LoginGuard` component, to display a login form instead of content, if user is not logged in.
2. I decided to make requests to API and save the state with `useSWR`, which I used to build a custom `useUser` hook, which uses `/api/user` endpoint to get user object.
3. When my `login` function gets a response from API, it calls `mutate(/api/user)`.
4. This immediately repaints all components that depend on `useUser` hook, such as `LoginGuard`.
5. After `LoginGuard` is updated with `user` which is not null, it no longer displays my `LoginForm`, and it becomes unmounted.
6. I built this login form with Formik. In it, I'm using the `setSubmitting` callback to tell it when I already got an update from the server. However, because I call it right after awaiting for the `login()` promise, by the time I call it, the component is already unmounted, and I get the React error.

Here's my code (with irrelevant parts removed):

```
export const LoginGuard: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const { user, error, isValidating } = useUser()
    if (isValidating) return <div>Loading...</div>
    if (error) return <div>Couldn't load user</div>
    if (!user)
        return (
            <div>
                You should login
                <LoginForm />
            </div>
        )
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default function LoginForm() {
    return (
        <Formik<LoginRequest>
            // ...
            onSubmit={async (input, { setSubmitting }) => {
                try {
                    await login(input)
                } finally {
                    setSubmitting(false)
                }
            }}
        >
            // ...
        </Formik>
    )
}

export async function login(request: LoginRequest) {
    mutate('/api/user', { user: null }, false)
    const { data } = await axios.post<LoginResponse>('/api/login', request, {
        validateStatus: (status) => [200, 401].includes(status)
    })
    const { user } = data
    mutate('/api/user', { user }, false)
    return data
}

export function useUser(user: User | null = null) {
    const { data, error, isValidating } = useSWR<{ user: User | null }>(
        '/api/user',
        {
            initialData: { user }
        }
    )
    return {
        user: data?.user,
        error,
        isValidating
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

I understand what this error means and why it happens. I also know a couple of ways to just make it "go away", but they seem like inelegant hacks.

What I don't understand is how to structure my code in such a way that this doesn't happen to me. I obviously made a beginner React mistake here, but I'm just not sure where exactly.

Also, is using `useSWR` to save the global state like user a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I didn't correctly understand the Formik API. All I had to do was replace `onSubmit` handler with `onSubmit={login}`. It takes a promise, awaits for it and handles `submitting` status on its' own.